# Cant use npm as provider with puppet

Tags: puppet, npm

I am attempting to do the following in puppet:

```
package { 'bower':
    ensure   => present,
    provider => 'npm',
    require  => Class['nodejs'],
    before   => [ Exec['npm_install'], Exec['grunt_build'] ],
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
err: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter provider failed on Package[bower]: Invalid package provider 'npm' at
```

I have tried using both puppetlabs-nodejs and willdurand-nodejs without success and have also manually installed npm then tried to apply the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own class to install node but used puppetlabs-nodejs custom provider https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-nodejs/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/package/npm.rb

It seems that as per https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/plugins_in_modules.html
pluginsync = true needs be added to /etc/puppet/puppet.conf on the nodes.

Comment: Please note that this has been default for years. Are you using an ancient release of Puppet? Or do you use packages from an ill maintained source?

Comment: I am using 2.7.25 which is provided by Amazon Linux repos. Should I be using the puppet repo instead? First time I tried that I ran into some issues and stuff to using the version in the amazon repo.

Comment: I see. In `2.7.25`, the setting was indeed not yet the default upstream. But most packagers included the setting in the stock `puppet.conf` that came with the package, if I recall correctly. Amazon did not, evidently. - Do consider switching to a source that offers more recent packages. You may encounter modules that are not compatible with `2.7.x`.